# Building a retaining wall around our shed - moisture barrier needed?

Tags: shed, landscaping, retaining-wall

I'd like to build a retaining wall/large planter around our shed to create some scenery and block the "crawspace" underneath the shed.  Should we use a moisture barrier against the exterior walls of the shed for additional protection against rotting (shed is wood siding), or should the stones for the planter provide sufficient protection?

Comment: What did you end up using as a moisture barrier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the planter is going to be in direct contact with wood, absolutely. Concrete is porous and it will be permanently saturated with water.

Comment: Many thanks. I'd mark the answer as helpful but I guess I don't have the reputation to do so yet :)

Comment: Figured out the check mark!  Thanks again for the input.